# Silverstripe bulk save all dataobjects

Tags: silverstripe

I've added URLSegments to DataObjects (Products) so I can then display the ProductName as the URL....the code works fine:

```
public function onBeforeWrite(){
    if($this->Name){
        $this->URLSegment = SiteTree::GenerateURLSegment($this->Name);
        if($object = DataObject::get_one($this->ClassName, "URLSegment='".$this->URLSegment."' AND ID !=".$this->ID)){
            $this->URLSegment = $this->URLSegment.'-'.$this->ID;
        }
    } else {
        $this->URLSegment = SiteTree::GenerateURLSegment($this->ClassName.'-'.$this->ID);
    }
    parent::onBeforeWrite();
}
```

But, I have over 1000 Products...is there any way of generating a bulk save for all Product Dataobjects in code (ie as a one-off) so I don't have to manually save each through the CMS??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to implement drzax solution, then found this, which implements it as a task. This task was created to add URLSegments to products, so fits my needs perfectly...

http://www.balbuss.com/creating-tasks/

Answer (score 1):

Just create a controller with an index function and use more or less the same code.

```
<?php

class UpdateProducts extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        $products = DataObject::get('Products');

        foreach ($products as $product) {

            if (!$product->URLSegment) {
                $product->write();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function once from the browser at http://example.com/UpdateProducts

This isn't super efficient so it really is only a one off. If the script times out, you can just run it again as the if statement in there means only products without a URLSegment will be updated.